Execution failed for task ':app ' in Flutter project with Mapbox
I'm encountering an error in my Flutter project while trying to build the app. The error seems to be related to duplicate classes in the Mapbox SDK. I am using mapbox_maps_flutter  and flutter_mapbox_navigation both.
Error:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
   > Duplicate class com.mapbox.common.module.okhttp.CallbackWrapper found in modules jetified-common-24.5.0-runtime (com.mapbox.common:common:24.5.0) and jetified-okhttp-23.8.0-runtime (com.mapbox.common:okhttp:23.8.0)
     Duplicate class com.mapbox.common.module.okhttp.CallbackWrapper$RequestCallback found in modules jetified-common-24.5.0-runtime (com.mapbox.common:common:24.5.0) and jetified-okhttp-23.8.0-runtime (com.mapbox.common:okhttp:23.8.0)
     Duplicate class com.mapbox.common.module.okhttp.HttpCallback found in modules jetified-common-24.5.0-runtime (com.mapbox.common:common:24.5.0) and jetified-okhttp-23.8.0-runtime (com.mapbox.common:okhttp:23.8.0)
     Duplicate class com.mapbox.common.module.okhttp.IdGenerator found in modules jetified-common-24.5.0-runtime (com.mapbox.common:common:24.5.0) and jetified-okhttp-23.8.0-runtime (com.mapbox.common:okhttp:23.8.0)
     Duplicate class com.mapbox.common.module.okhttp.LazyClient found in modules jetified-common-24.5.0-runtime (com.mapbox.common:common:24.5.0) and jetified-okhttp-23.8.0-runtime (com.mapbox.common:okhttp:23.8.0)
     Duplicate class com.mapbox.common.module.okhttp.MapboxOkHttpService found in modules jetified-common-24.5.0-runtime (com.mapbox.common:common:24.5.0) and jetified-okhttp-23.8.0-runtime (com.mapbox.common:okhttp:23.8.0)
     Duplicate class com.mapbox.common.module.okhttp.MapboxOkHttpService$1 found in modules jetified-common-24.5.0-runtime (com.mapbox.common:common:24.5.0) and jetified-okhttp-23.8.0-runtime (com.mapbox.common:okhttp:23.8.0)
     Duplicate class com.mapbox.common.module.okhttp.MapboxOkHttpService$HttpServiceGetLifecycleStateCallback found in modules jetified-common-24.5.0-runtime (com.mapbox.common:common:24.5.0) and jetified-okhttp-23.8.0-runtime (com.mapbox.common:okhttp:23.8.0)
     Duplicate class com.mapbox.common.module.okhttp.MapboxOkHttpService$HttpServiceLifecycleObserver found in modules jetified-common-24.5.0-runtime (com.mapbox.common:common:24.5.0) and jetified-okhttp-23.8.0-runtime (com.mapbox.common:okhttp:23.8.0)
     Duplicate class com.mapbox.common.module.okhttp.MapboxOkHttpService$HttpServiceOfflineSwitchObserver found in modules jetified-common-24.5.0-runtime (com.mapbox.common:common:24.5.0) and jetified-okhttp-23.8.0-runtime (com.mapbox.common:okhttp:23.8.0)
     Duplicate class com.mapbox.common.module.okhttp.MapboxOkHttpService$QueuedRequest found in modules jetified-common-24.5.0-runtime (com.mapbox.common:common:24.5.0) and jetified-okhttp-23.8.0-runtime (com.mapbox.common:okhttp:23.8.0)
     Duplicate class com.mapbox.common.module.okhttp.NetworkUsageListener found in modules jetified-common-24.5.0-runtime (com.mapbox.common:common:24.5.0) and jetified-okhttp-23.8.0-runtime (com.mapbox.common:okhttp:23.8.0)
     Duplicate class com.mapbox.common.module.okhttp.NetworkUsageListener$NetworkUsageMetricCallback found in modules jetified-common-24.5.0-runtime (com.mapbox.common:common:24.5.0) and jetified-okhttp-23.8.0-runtime (com.mapbox.common:okhttp:23.8.0)

     Go to the documentation to learn how to <a href="d.android.com/r/tools/classpath-sync-errors">Fix dependency resolution errors</a>.



build.gragle:android
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = "../build"
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(":app")
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

build.gragle:app
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    // START: FlutterFire Configuration
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    // END: FlutterFire Configuration
    id "kotlin-android"
    // The Flutter Gradle Plugin must be applied after the Android and Kotlin Gradle plugins.
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file("local.properties")
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader("UTF-8") { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty("flutter.versionCode")
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = "1"
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty("flutter.versionName")
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = "1.0"
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.nursing_application"
    compileSdk = 34
    ndkVersion = flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId = "com.example.nursing_application"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdk = 21
        targetSdk = flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode = flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName = flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig = signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source = "../.."
}

dependencies {
    implementation platform("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-bom:1.8.0")
    
}


gradle.properties
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4G -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
SDK_REGISTRY_TOKEN=sk.XXX
MAPBOX_DOWNLOADS_TOKEN=sk.XXX

settings.gradle
pluginManagement {
    def flutterSdkPath = {
        def properties = new Properties()
        file("local.properties").withInputStream { properties.load(it) }
        def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
        assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
        return flutterSdkPath
    }()

    includeBuild("$flutterSdkPath/packages/flutter_tools/gradle")

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}

plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "com.android.application" version "7.3.0" apply false
    // START: FlutterFire Configuration
    id "com.google.gms.google-services" version "4.3.15" apply false
    // END: FlutterFire Configuration
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "2.0.0" apply false
}

include ":app"

pubspec.yaml
name: nursing_application
description: "A new Flutter project."

publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=3.4.3 <4.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.6
  get: ^4.6.6
  firebase_core: ^2.24.2
  firebase_auth: ^4.16.0
  cloud_firestore: ^4.14.0
  firebase_storage: ^11.7.7
  location: ^7.0.0
  location_picker_flutter_map: ^3.0.1
  mapbox_maps_flutter: ^2.1.0
  permission_handler: ^11.3.1
  http: ^1.2.2
  flutter_mapbox_navigation: ^0.2.2
  

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_lints: ^3.0.0

flutter:

  uses-material-design: true

 

Cleaned and rebuilt the project.
Clean Caches
Do something like this (suggested by chatgpt)
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.mapbox.common:common:24.5.0'
    implementation ('com.mapbox.common:okhttp:23.8.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.mapbox.common', module: 'common'
    }
}


Hello, were you able to solve this?
